# Trying to figure out all cities larger than 2000000 people locate in a area using DBPEDIA

Tags: geolocation, sparql, geospatial, dbpedia

Hi I'm trying to locate all cities inside a area with more people than a threshold.

THis SPARQL query works fine,

```
SELECT DISTINCT  *
    WHERE  {
        ?city rdfs:label ?citylabel ;
              dbpedia-owl:country ?country ;
              dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?population .
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City }
        UNION
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement }
        UNION
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Town }
        ?city geo:geometry ?geo .
        ?country rdfs:label ?countrylabel .
        FILTER (
            lang(?countrylabel) = 'en' &&
            bif:st_intersects(?geo, bif:st_point(2.0, 50.0), 200) && 
            ?population > 1000000
        )
    }
```

giving me points 200 km near to the Coordinate (2, 50) - close Paris

however when I change the thrshold to 2000000, the results seems random

```
SELECT DISTINCT  *
    WHERE  {
        ?city rdfs:label ?citylabel ;
              dbpedia-owl:country ?country ;
              dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?population .
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City }
        UNION
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement }
        UNION
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Town }
        ?city geo:geometry ?geo .
        ?country rdfs:label ?countrylabel .
        FILTER (
            lang(?countrylabel) = 'en' &&
            bif:st_intersects(?geo, bif:st_point(2.0, 50.0), 200) && ?population > 2000000
        )
    }
```

What Am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Some information missing on my original post.
1) I am trying to run query on my personal server. On DBPedia.org the query seems to work fine.
2) I basic followed this link to enable spatial queries. Summarizing I've ran DB.DBA.RDF_GEO_FILL() to create the geometry property/index followed by checkpoint. I guess there is no other step to take.
3) Making more clear how random the results seems to be the following query works:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  ?countrylabel
    (group_concat(distinct ?citylabel ; separator = "||")
                        AS ?city_set)
    WHERE  {
        ?city rdfs:label ?citylabel ;
              dbpedia-owl:country ?country ;
              dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?population .
        # City is a Town or Settlement or City
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City }
        UNION
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement }
        UNION
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Town }
        ?city geo:geometry ?geo .
        ?country rdfs:label ?countrylabel .
        FILTER (
            lang(?countrylabel) = "en" &&
            bif:st_intersects(?geo, bif:st_point(2.0, 48.0), 200) &&
            ?population > 2000000.0
        )
    }
```

Returning Paris as you can see. Notice the latitude is 48.0

```
{"head": {
    "link": [],
    "vars": [
        "countrylabel",
        "city_set"
    ]
},
"results": {
    "distinct": false,
    "ordered": true,
    "bindings": [
        {
            "countrylabel": {
                "type": "literal",
                "xml:lang": "en",
                "value": "France"
            },
            "city_set": {
                "type": "literal",
                "value": "Paris"
            }
        }
    ]
}}
```

However when I change the latitude to 50. everything changes:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  ?countrylabel
    (group_concat(distinct ?citylabel ; separator = "||")
                        AS ?city_set)
    WHERE  {
        ?city rdfs:label ?citylabel ;
              dbpedia-owl:country ?country ;
              dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?population .
        # City is a Town or Settlement or City
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City }
        UNION
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement }
        UNION
        { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Town }
        ?city geo:geometry ?geo .
        ?country rdfs:label ?countrylabel .
        FILTER (
            lang(?countrylabel) = "en" &&
            bif:st_intersects(?geo, bif:st_point(2.0, 50.0), 200) &&
            ?population > 2000000.0
        )
    }
```

And the results are crazy(!!!):

```
{"head": {
    "link": [],
    "vars": [
        "countrylabel",
        "city_set"
    ]
},
"results": {
    "distinct": false,
    "ordered": true,
    "bindings": [
        {
            "countrylabel": {
                "type": "literal",
                "xml:lang": "en",
                "value": "Poland"
            },
            "city_set": {
                "type": "literal",
                "value": "Lublin Voivodeship||Voivodia de Lublin"
            }
        },
        {
            "countrylabel": {
                "type": "literal",
                "xml:lang": "en",
                "value": "Mexico"
            },
            "city_set": {
                "type": "literal",
                "value": "Guanajuato"
            }
        },
        {
            "countrylabel": {
                "type": "literal",
                "xml:lang": "en",
                "value": "United Kingdom"
            },
            "city_set": {
                "type": "literal",
                "value": "Inner London"
            }
        },
        {
            "countrylabel": {
                "type": "literal",
                "xml:lang": "en",
                "value": "Nigeria"
            },
            "city_set": {
                "type": "literal",
                "value": "Kano (estado)||Kano State"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

So I guess there is something wrong with the indices virtuoso created, however I have no clue what I suppose to do about it.

Comment: What do you mean the results seem  random?  When I run your second query, I get Paris and Nord as results.  (I don't know offhand what cities in France should qualify.)

Comment: Also, you can simplify `{ ?city a type1 } union { ?city a type2 } ...` with **values**.  You'd do `values ?type { dbpedia-owl:City dbpedia-owl:Town dbpedia-owl:Settlement } ?city a ?type`.  Much cleaner, in my opinion.

Comment: Also, you should probably use `langMatches(lang(?countrylabel),'en')` rather than `lang(?countrylabel) = 'en'`.

Comment: Ok, it turns out it might be a virtuoso version problem. When I switched from Virtuoso 7.1 to 7.2 everything seems to work. I will be running more tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean that the results "seem random".  I'm not sure how many places in France have a population over two million, but the query returns two places: Paris and Nord.  If you clean up the query a little bit (e.g., use **value** to simplify the **union**, and a property path to get right of the **?country** variable (unless you want the country variable, in which case keep it), and using **langMatches** instead of **lang(…) = …**, and filter the language of the city label too:

```sql
select distinct * where {
  values ?type { dbpedia-owl:City dbpedia-owl:Settlement dbpedia-owl:Town }
  ?city a ?type ;
        rdfs:label ?citylabel ;
        dbpedia-owl:country/rdfs:label ?countrylabel ;
        dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?population ;
        geo:geometry ?geo 
  filter (    langMatches(lang(?countrylabel),'en')
           && langMatches(lang(?citylabel),'en')
           && bif:st_intersects(?geo, bif:st_point(2.0, 50.0), 200)
           && ?population > 2000000 )
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3ACity%20dbpedia-owl%3ASettlement%20dbpedia-owl%3ATown%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20a%20%3Ftype%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcitylabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Acountry%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountrylabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3ApopulationTotal%20%3Fpopulation%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20geo%3Ageometry%20%3Fgeo%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fcountrylabel%29%2C%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fcitylabel%29%2C%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20bif%3Ast_intersects%28%3Fgeo%2C%20bif%3Ast_point%282.0%2C%2050.0%29%2C%20200%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20%3Fpopulation%20%3E%202000000%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: When I query to the dbpedia.org endpoint the results are quite good. The problem is on my personal virtuoso instalation. The results for the same query are a city in Mexico and other one in Korea. That's random. With out the population constrain,  everything works as equal as the dbpedia endpoint.

Comment: @FernandoFerreira I'd check to see whether there's anything you have to do to enable the geospatial bif functionality.

Comment: Yes I will check. Anyway, thanks for helping with the query. Your tips make it better indeed.

Comment: I will also edit the original post, to make more clear my problem